# How to use ManagedExecutorService with @Asynchronous method?

Tags: asynchronous, wildfly, java-ee-7

I have a Java EE app that's deployed on WildFly AS. 
I have a method annotated with `@Asynchronous` and I need to set the max number of threads for this method.
I configured a new `<managed-executor-service>` in server config, but I don't know how to bind it to an async method.

Answer (score 1):

This link:  https://developer.jboss.org/message/851027#851027

provides a good answer to how (or when) to use @Asynchronous and when to use  JSR-236 ExecutorService and concurrency utilities:

> In short, @Asynchronous is a annotation (EE6) to mark an EJB method as async.
>   You can invoke the method and keep the future object to check whether the method is finished and get the result. The EJB Concurrency Utilities are provided to have a safe way in EE7 to delegate work to a parallel thread. Threads started by this ConcurrentUtilities are managed by the container.
>   In difference to a direct start of a Thread (which is not allowed for an EE application). There is less overhead than using @Async and you have a bit more control.

See also this link about how to inject a MES:

- http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/injecting_an_executorservice_with_java